# assigning values to a numpy matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am encountering syntax error at line 7 when I am running the code.

```
import numpy as np
offset = 2

V1 = np.ones((30,21))
O = np.zeros(an-offset,pn-offset)
for i in range(offset+1,an):
  for j in range(offset+1,pn):
    O(i-offset,j-offset) = (np.absolute(np.dot(np.array(V1)[:,i],np.array(V2)[:,j])))/(np.linalg.norm(V1[:,i]),np.linalg.norm(V2[:,j]))
```

SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
O(i-offset,j-offset)
```

Should be this:

```
O[i-offset,j-offset]
```